# trying to make a text say a variable, but it just shows [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, html

When I press get money, it will add [object HTMLDivElement]1 instead of just 1. this is the code:

```
<script>
    function cash(){
        var Cash = 0
        document.getElementById("Cash").textContent = Cash
    }
        function text(){
            Cash = Cash + Number(1)
            document.getElementById("Cash").textContent = Cash
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="cash()">
    <div id="Cash"></div>
    <button class="button-long" onclick="text()">Get Money</button>
</body>
```

I do not know what is happening and I have found nothing else on how to fix this. The CSS has nothing to do with it, I have checked the code many times and changed and tested a lot of times as well and I have found nothing on this website or any other website about this. I would like some help on this one as I do not know what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the `Cash` variable inside the `cash` function, which is not visible to the `text` function. To fix this, you need to move the `Cash` declaration outside the `cash` function where is becomes visible to both function as follows:

```
<head>  
  <script>
    var Cash = 0

    function cash(){
      document.getElementById("Cash").textContent = Cash
    }

    function text(){
      Cash = Cash + Number(1)
      document.getElementById("Cash").textContent = Cash
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="cash()">
    <div id="Cash"></div>
    <button class="button-long" onclick="text()">Get Money</button>
</body>
```

Given that `Cash` was not visible to the `text` function, you may now be wondering why you observed `[object HTMLDivElement]` for the value of `Cash` inside the `text` function instead of `undefined`. The reason for that is because you also have an element in the DOM with an id of the same name, i.e. `Cash`, which becomes a [global property in the document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/3634032). By declaring `var Cash = 0` globally, that will shadow the Cash reference to the DOM element.